# Conditional search and replace in Shell

Tags: shell, sed, csh, tcsh

I have a string processing requirement where I want to take a line from line number n and edit it (replace @2 to @3) and then insert the new edited string to line number n+1

Here is what my input file looks like

Input File:-

> ```
> x/a   y/a   z/a
> x/a@2 y/a@2 z/a@2
> x/b   y/b   z/b
> x/b@2 y/b@2 z/b@2
> ```

Expected output is as below. Notice the third line with @3. This is what I am expecting.

> ```
> x/a   y/a   z/a
> x/a@2 y/a@2 z/a@2
> x/a@3 y/a@3 z/a@3
> x/b   y/b   z/b
> x/b@2 y/b@2 z/b@2
> ```

What I have tried:-
I have basic understanding of sed. So i was able to search and replace a string using:

```
sed '/a@2/  s/a@2/a@3/' -i $file
```

However I am not able to figure out a way to insert it to next line where it was picked up.

Any help will be appreciated. 
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print the line you want to edit, before you edit it:

```
sed '/a@2/{ p; s/a@2/a@3/g; }'
```